# What's the best way scale clustrix with docker?

Tags: database, docker, containers

I'm new to using containers and am wondering some of the best practices for database processes inside of containers. I was planning on adding database processing nodes in new containers and scaling them out as I max out demand (basically using containers as a microservice). From what I've read anything involving data should not be incorporated into containers.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Cloud Architect at Clustrix. Currently, we are not officially supporting containers to host ClustrixDB. As you pointed out there are some challenges associated with containers and distributed data. However, we are actively working on productizing ClustrixDB for Docker containers and others.

If you're interested in attempting this before we have something productized, we can provide some guidance. You're welcome to ask us questions on our community forum: https://support.clustrix.com/hc/communities/public/topics

Alex